# Append new column to existing table using SAS

Tags: sas

I have a `do loop` in which I do calculation on new variable and results are stored as additional column, this column-s (at each iteration) should be attached to the output table defined by macro.

[Here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222386/insert-into-specific-column-from-other-table) something similar has been asked but the answer is not acceptable, the last answer is not compatible with `sas` command but very close, getting incomplete script with following:

```
    proc sql;
         update &outlib..&out. 
         set var._iqr = b.&var._iqr
         from &outlib..&out. as a 
         left join cal_resul as b
         on a.id_client=b.id_client 
         and a.reference_date=b.reference_date; 
    quit;
```

Here is my attempt which works but very slow:

```
    proc sql; create table &outlib..&out. as select * from &inlib..&in.; quit; /* the input is as a basis for output table */
    proc sql; alter table &outlib..&out. add &var._iqr numeric; quit; /* create empty column to be filled at each iteration */

    proc sql;
         update &outlib..&out. as a
         set &var._iqr=(select b.&var._iqr from cal_resul as b
         where a.id_client=b.id_client 
         and a.reference_date=b.reference_date 
         and a.data_source=b.data_source);
    quit;
```

Attempt 2:

This is somewhat faster:

```
    proc sort data=cal_resul; by id_client reference_date data_source; run;

    data &outlib..&out.;
         update &outlib..&out. cal_resul; 
         by id_client reference_date data_source;
    run;
```

Simple left join (adding new column into existing table is way faster) but with left join I did not figure out how I can update (always retain the same dataset) the `&outlib..&out.` at each iteration. Many thanks for any help;

Comment: You cannot add a variable to an existing dataset.  You must make a new dataset.  You can, if you want, use the same name for the new dataset as the old one.  Why are you trying to do each new variable separately? Why not just generate all of the new variables in one step?

Comment: The question you linked to is about trying to update values in an existing variable. Not creating a new variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ADD a variable to a dataset you will have to make a new dataset.  (Your ALTER TABLE statement will create a new dataset and copy over all of the observations.)

Looks like your data has three key variables.  So use those in merging the new data to the old.

For example to make a new variable in HAVE named EXAMPLE_IQR using the variable EXAMPLE in the dataset NEW you could use code like this.  I have used macro variables to show how you might use those macro variables as the parameters to a macro.  It sounds like you don't want the process to add new observations to the existing dataset so I have added a check for that using the IN= dataset option.

```
%let base=work.have;
%let indata=work.new;
%let var=example;

data &base ;
   merge &base(in=inbase)
         &indata(keep=id_client reference_date data_source &var 
                 rename=(&var=&var._iqr)
                )
   ;
   by id_client reference_date data_source;
   if inbase;
run;
```

Comment: I actually solved with:    data &outlib..&out.;
         update &outlib..&out. cal_resul; 
         by id_client reference_date data_source;
    run; I just uncessarily overcomplicating it without realizing the I can mantain the same dataset as you have shown with `merge`. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds ok. Note that the MERGE and UPDATE statements will handle missing values in the CAL_RESULT datasets different.